# net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

estoy haciendo una instalación de un proyecto wordpress en un vps y tengo el siguente problema en la primera pantalla a la hora de empezar la instalación no me cargan ni los css ni los js ni dependencias adjunto una línea con el error que se repite para cada archivo

GET http://localhost:81/example/wp-admin/js/language-chooser.min.js?ver=5.5 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

por alguna razón me llama todo desde el localhost y no desde el dominio.
cuando accedo al proyecto desde la ip me funciona bien pero cuando accedo desde el dominio no me funciona para nada bien

utilizo nginx  y tengo la siguiente configuracion

```
#inicio example
server{
server_name example.com.co;
location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:81/example/;
}

    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com.co/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com.co/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    #include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server{
    if ($host = example.com.co) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


listen 80;
server_name example.com.co;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
#fin example
```

el servidor es un ubuntu 18.04

Comment: ¿No deberías poner aquí `proxy_pass http://localhost:81/example/;` la URL del dominio?

Comment: Se supone que cuando acceda por el puerto 443 ssl o el 80 lo debe redireccionar internamente a la ruta del proxy_passs que sería la ruta donde se está ejecutando localmente el servicio.